# Property Added to Postgres Row Always Shows Up undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql, object, express

I am adding a property to each object returned from my postgres db. The new property shows up when I console.log() the whole object, but it comes out undefined every time I try to access it or store it into another variable.

This is the code where I add the property to the objects:

```
for(var i = 0; i < teams.rows.length; i++) {
    teams.rows[i].year = year
}
async.map(teams.rows, leagueResults, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results)
    cb(err, results)
})
```

Then I try and access the year property in leagueResults:

```
console.log(team)
team = "\'"+team.team_id+"\'"
var year = team.year
console.log('team', team, team.year)
```

the console logging team.year always comes up "undefined" Does anyone know why and how I can fix this? I am using the pg npm module to connect / query my postgres server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the value of `team` with a string and the new string won't have the same properties as your old `team` object.

The solution is to move `var year = team.year` *before* `team = "\'"+team.team_id+"\'"` and use that `year` value instead of `team.year`.